# Trim string with specific charset

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Is there a function in Delphi equivalent to Cocoa's `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet`?

What I need is to eliminate all the characters included in a charset that are found at the beginning or the end of a string. There can be none, one or more starting or ending the string...

What would be the most efficient way to do this in Delphi?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far i know there is not exist  a RTL function like that. But you can check the [`JclStrings`](http://jcl.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/jcl/trunk/jcl/source/common/JclStrings.pas?view=markup) unit part of the [JCL project](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JCL_Download) , which include the [`StrTrimCharsLeft`](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JCL_Help:StrTrimCharsLeft@AnsiString@TSysCharSet) and 
[`StrTrimCharsRight`](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JCL_Help:StrTrimCharsRight@AnsiString@TSysCharSet) functions.

```
function StrTrimCharsLeft(const S: string; const Chars: TCharValidator): string; overload;
function StrTrimCharsLeft(const S: string; const Chars: array of Char): string; overload;
function StrTrimCharRight(const S: string; C: Char): string;
function StrTrimCharsRight(const S: string; const Chars: TCharValidator): string; overload;
function StrTrimCharsRight(const S: string; const Chars: array of Char): string; overload;
```

Comment: Thank you!I believe the best solution is to take @David Heffernan's advise and create "inspired by" equivalent JCL functions instead of using the whole framework. I hope this doesn't raise any issues regarding their licensing...

Answer (score 1):

To the very best of my knowledge, the RTL does not include such a function. You could use regular expressions to fill the gap:

```
function MyTrim(const Input: string; const TrimChars: string): string;
begin
  Result := TRegEx.Replace(Input, Format('^[%s]*', [TrimChars]), '');
  Result := TRegEx.Replace(Result, Format('[%s]*$', [TrimChars]), '');
end;
```

I'm quite sure this is not the best performing solution, but it would be hard to find something much simpler.

Comment: Thank you David!Your solution works fine.I'm going to do some performance tests against the other mentioned solution (JCL) and publish the results here.Performance is key to this project.

Comment: The regex won't be faster than the JCL code. Is trimming strings really the bottleneck to your project?

Comment: I'm working on a NLP project.Previous framework version is Obj-C. Now I'm translating into Delphi to have a Windows version.The parsing is heavy under learning mode.This function is called at least once per parsed word.I'm parsing whole books.Using JCL just for this feels like using a hammer to kill an ant... It doesn't need to be faster, just not too much slower.

Comment: @MiguelE JCL is certainly a big hammer. But just take the source code to the two functions that you need. They do stand alone and they are trivial to implement your self in any case. A regex is a hammer also, in this context! A simple loop like that JCL code does the job.

Comment: Thank you again David. I'm taking your advise and creating simile JCL functions.